# TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, technical-indicator

I'm trying to calculate Money Flow Index for bitcoin price.

To do this I'm using gdax, pandas and pyti.

Here's my code:

```
import gdax
import pandas as pd
from pyti.money_flow_index import money_flow_index as mfi

public_client = gdax.PublicClient()
historic = public_client.get_product_historic_rates('BTC-USD', granularity=60)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 30)
df = pd.DataFrame(historic)
df.columns = ['Time', 'Low', 'High', 'Open', 'Close', 'Volume']
df = df.head(n=30)

print(df, '\n')
close_data = df['Close'][0]
high_data = df['High'][0]
low_data = df['Low'][0]
volume_data = df['Volume'][0]
period = 14
print(mfi(close_data, high_data, low_data, volume_data, period))
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tiiii.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(mfi(close_data, high_data, low_data, volume_data, period))
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyti\money_
flow_index.py", line 19, in money_flow_index
    close_data, high_data, low_data, volume
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyti\catch_
errors.py", line 26, in check_for_input_len_diff
    arrays_len = [len(arr) for arr in args]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyti\catch_
errors.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    arrays_len = [len(arr) for arr in args]
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

**Edit:** 
OK so now I'm using:

```
close_data = df['Close']
high_data = df['High']
low_data = df['Low']
volume_data = df['Volume']
```

And here's what I'm getting:

```
            0
0         NaN
1         NaN
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
5         NaN
6         NaN
..        ...
23  97.914228
24  97.816960
25  96.440309
26  94.668462
27  94.340548
28  91.255057
29  87.706573

[30 rows x 1 columns]
```

I don't understand the order of the values. Also why am I not getting the full list?

P.S. Thanks for the help Rahul and timgeb!

Comment: Please don't edit your question to be another question after it has been answered. Accept the answer that solved the original problem, then ask a new question (after proper research and attempts).

Comment: Hope I didn't break any rules. I thought I was adding more details to the original question.

Comment: Well sometimes this is a judgement call. I would argue that the original question was how to solve the `TypeError` and that your new question is sufficiently different from solving a `TypeError` that it warrants a new post.

Comment: Fair enough. But don't you think that posting pretty much the same code again is kind of pointless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `money_flow_index` calls [check_for_input_len_diff](https://github.com/kylejusticemagnuson/pyti/blob/master/pyti/catch_errors.py) and throws an error on line 26 when it tries to accumulate the length of the arguments `close_data, high_data, low_data, volume` you provided to `money_flow_index` (imported as `mfi`).

The comments indicate that these arguments are supposed to be data sets (or at least data structures with a length), but you provided a float number, which has no length.

Answer (score 0):

I have extracted functions from `pyti` module. This is how your code actually execute inside modules.

```
def money_flow_index (close_data, high_data, low_data, volume, period):
    check_for_input_len_diff(
        close_data, high_data, low_data, volume
    )

def check_for_input_len_diff(*args):
    arrays_len = [len(arr) for arr in args]

print(
    money_flow_index(
        close_data, high_data,
        low_data, volume_data, period
    )
)
```

So `money_flow_index` need every argument as `array`. you are providing `numpy.float64`